# Is Captain America getting new shield?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

While watching [Spider-Man: Homecoming (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2250912/) I found this scene,

[image]

**Is Stark creating new shield for Captain America ??**. Why would Tony Stark do that, considering they had a bad fight ?